# list of items based on Webrequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, webforms

I am wondering what would be the best way to create a list of items in a asp.net web form with c# based on information I get from a HttpWebRequest. In my Page_Load I make a web request to a Wowza media server that returns xml. I save this in a string and then use xmlreader to get the data I need. After this is done, I want to view this in a list in my web form. I hope I was clear enough.

I also want to be able to click the items which will run a function.

EDIT:
I can't for the life of me get the suggested answer to work, when I run the code the website it completely blank. Here are the c# and html file codes:

```css
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<String> LiveStreamms = new List<String>();
        string xml = "<ArrayOfLiveStream xmlns:i='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns='http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MvcApplication1.Models'><LiveStream><Name>Test1</Name><Path>Path1</Path></LiveStream></ArrayOfLiveStream>";
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml));
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(reader);
        LiveStreams.Data = doc.OuterXml;
        LiveStreams.XPath = "/LiveStream/Name";
    }
}
```

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" CodeFile="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test" runat="server"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
  <head runat="server">
    <title>ASP.NET Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

      <asp:XmlDataSource
        id="LiveStreams"
        runat="server"
        XPath="/ArrayOfLiveStream"/>

      <asp:DataList
        id="PeopleDataList"
        DataSourceID="LiveStreams"
        Runat="server">

        <ItemTemplate>
          <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4">
            <tr>
              <td style="vertical-align:top; width:120">
                <asp:Label id="PathNameLabel" Text='<%# XPath("Livestream/Path") %>' runat="server" />, 
                <asp:Label id="NameLabel" Text='<%# XPath("Livestream/Name") %>' runat="server" />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:DataList>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Now you have edited your question you've asked for yet more functionality and its a mixture of two questions, I've answered below how to do the data list, there are examples of calling a server side and client side function all over this site, I'd suggest looking there for that, as its really a duplicate question. Plus you don't mention which it is you want to call.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an XmlDataSource along with a datalist to do this there is a good write up on msdn [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228087(v=vs.100).aspx) about how to do this
basically you take the xml and use XPath queries in templates to create the desired effect.

Because the article may go out of date I include their sample but this is not my code.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
  <head runat="server">
    <title>ASP.NET Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <asp:XmlDataSource
        id="PeopleDataSource"
        runat="server"
        XPath="/People/Person"
        DataFile="~/App_Data/people.xml" />

      <asp:DataList
        id="PeopleDataList"
        DataSourceID="PeopleDataSource"
        Runat="server">

        <ItemTemplate>
          <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4">
            <tr>
              <td style="vertical-align:top; width:120">
                <asp:Label id="LastNameLabel" Text='<%# XPath("Name/LastName")%>' runat="server" />, 
                <asp:Label id="FirstNameLabel" Text='<%# XPath("Name/FirstName")%>' runat="server" />
              </td>
              <td valign="top">
                 <asp:Label id="StreetLabel" Text='<%# XPath("Address/Street") %>' runat="server" /><br />
                 <asp:Label id="CityLabel" Text='<%# XPath("Address/City") %>' runat="server" />, 
                 <asp:Label id="RegionLabel" Text='<%# XPath("Address/Region") %>' runat="server" />
                 <asp:Label id="ZipCodeLabel" Text='<%# XPath("Address/ZipCode") %>' runat="server" />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:DataList>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

if you notice the xml is being loaded into the data source then that is being used in the data list templates, the XPath querys are being used per record with a qualified name. Its a bit like using a repeater.

Also note that you do not have to use an Xml File you can use the Data property on the XmlDataSource to bind to an XmlDocument you have created from a string. Eg

The XmlDocument way:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(reader);
xmlDataSource.Data = doc.OuterXml;
xmlDataSource.XPath = "/People/Person";
```

The XDocument way:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
xmlDataSource.Data = doc.ToString();
xmlDataSource.XPath = "/People/Person";
```

The .Data property is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.xmldatasource.data(v=vs.110).aspx), Also note you can use a `<data>` tag to describe your data if its static (in your case its not). It's up to you as to which is best for you.

Comment: Is this really a good solution? will I have to have a xml file in my directory that my program writes the code it gets from my media server and then use this to update a list. That would mean the website would have to overwrite the content of the xml file every time I run the command.

Comment: edited you can bind to an xml document using the .Data property. So you can read your xml in as a string. Load it into XmlDocument or XDocument if you wish (XDocument is the new way) and then do what you want in the binder.

Comment: @user1254588 No, this technique stores the received data in an XmlDocument or XDocument object.  You can write it to file if you want to but as written it just stays in memory.